NATS Frontend -> Backend authentication, Backend -> Backend other type of authentication
So, i am using NATS, Angular and .NET.
In angular i connect the client to NATS server with JWT that is generated on login.
In .NET service i have to connect to NATS too for publish, subscribe logic but i have to generate new token on start, what if token expire while server is running.
Better solution will be to connect this .NET service with some kind of user/pass or secret token, but that is what i can't and dont know how.
My config file looks like:
# Operator named RW_Operator
operator: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlZDI1NTE5LW5rZXkifQ.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.iJuvBfktgJ6IJVHbC4M21xKcDQfZrVoYjrrlg4LTpgxM34VUHrAxNJuXetAIuCySjoQqenXUGryo9rj6ZJhRBg
# System Account named SYS
system_account: ADNISFSTYNVWYZACC7DQ66IYZ26NUZFY4TQ4RK7T2J43XSHQFHH6LY2P

websocket {
    port: 443
    no_tls: true
}

# configuration of the nats based resolver
resolver {
    type: full
    # Directory in which the account jwt will be stored
    dir: './jwt'
    # In order to support jwt deletion, set to true
    # If the resolver type is full delete will rename the jwt.
    # This is to allow manual restoration in case of inadvertent deletion.
    # To restore a jwt, remove the added suffix .delete and restart or send a reload signal.
    # To free up storage you must manually delete files with the suffix .delete.
    allow_delete: false
    # Interval at which a nats-server with a nats based account resolver will compare
    # it's state with one random nats based account resolver in the cluster and if needed, 
    # exchange jwt and converge on the same set of jwt.
    interval: "2m"
    # Timeout for lookup requests in case an account does not exist locally.
    timeout: "1.9s"
}

# Preload the nats based resolver with the system account jwt.
# This is not necessary but avoids a bootstrapping system account. 
# This only applies to the system account. Therefore other account jwt are not included here.
# To populate the resolver:
# 1) make sure that your operator has the account server URL pointing at your nats servers.
#    The url must start with: "nats://" 
#    nsc edit operator --account-jwt-server-url nats://localhost:4222
# 2) push your accounts using: nsc push --all
#    The argument to push -u is optional if your account server url is set as described.
# 3) to prune accounts use: nsc push --prune 
#    In order to enable prune you must set above allow_delete to true
# Later changes to the system account take precedence over the system account jwt listed here.
resolver_preload: {
    ADNISFSTYNVWYZACC7DQ66IYZ26NUZFY4TQ4RK7T2J43XSHQFHH6LY2P: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlZDI1NTE5LW5rZXkifQ.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.paEVbf-2vbxM4e7_8lQCB43Zh2f8UtVwDSiJi7Z9zdkBaBNksgc0bAaYRceJgUJUTf6FUGZacBvUT7dAgA5dBw,
}

Thanks if someone can help
